# Issue when installing Oracle SQL Developer on Debian Linux

Tags: java, linux, oracle, debian, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to install `Oracle SQL Devleoper` onto a `Debian Linux server`.

I have successfully installed and set up a Java JDK and JRE and have added the jdk path to the `sqldeveloper.conf` file:

```
SetSkipJ2SDKCheck true 
SetJavaHome /home/info/Java/jdk1.8.0_40
```

After doing this I get the following messages when running the `sqldeveloper.sh` file:

```
Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
WARNING: This product is certified on JDK 1.7.0_51.  You are attempting to run on JDK 1.8.0_40.  This product may not run correctly on this version of the JDK.
```

It remain stuck on this screen until you press `^C` to exit. It then prints the following message:

```
Error: SQL Developer can't recognize the JDK version
```

I have ensured the JDK is set up and working properly by running the following commands:

> update-alternatives --display java

Output:

```
java - auto mode
  link currently points to /home/info/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java
/home/info/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java - priority 100
Current 'best' version is '/home/info/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java'.
```

> update-alternative --display javac

Output:

```
javac - auto mode
  link currently points to /home/info/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/javac
/home/info/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/javac - priority 100
Current 'best' version is '/home/info/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/javac'.
```

> java -version

Output:

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

> javac -version

Output:

```
javac 1.8.0_40
```

How can I solve this issue of it not being able to recognize the JDK version?

**Update:**

I am using the following:

- Debian Linux Server.
- jdk1.8.0_40 (Java 8 Update 40)
- jre1.8.0_25 (Java 8 Update 25)
- sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm (following instructions from the [Oracle Website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-install-linux-1969676.html) and downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ran into a similar issue once and I can say I lost some few hours on it, had to remove all the old/irrelevant jdks predefined within the OS and reinstall the latest jdk myself and all that just to find out that i've made some typos when i've used "java update alternatives" in the 1-st place.

1. I would 1-st recommend you to check your commands again here is a [link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) that you can have for guidance on what to check again on update alternatives.
2. If you still have the same issue then try remove all the other jdks and reinstall the one you need it ( you will have only one this way )

Hope that helps - cheers.

PS: One more thing though that would probably worth to check: I am usually setting JAVA_HOME in the .bash_profile and not in sqldeveloper ( like detailed in [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/) or in the end of previous link )  thus rest assuring my whole environment addresses the same default jdk.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions; I have tried them, and still no luck in getting it to work :\

Comment: @James, can you please post the exact versions of all you are using please ? ( OS, sqldeveloper in particular )

Comment: ofcourse, I have just updated the question giving all of the information I can.

Comment: @James I've used Debian 7.0.8 and all ok to me here are the steps I've performed:   
1)install jdk as described here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps
2) rest assure jdk is correctly installed by running **update-alternatives --config java** and **update-alternatives --config javac**

Comment: @James just continuing ... 
3) install alien ( instead of rpm ) **sudo apt-get install alien**
4) install sqldeveloper using the following 2 commands 
**sudo alien --scripts sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm** and 
**sudo dpkg -i sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84-2_all.deb**
At this point you should  be good to go ( just run SqlDeveloper ) - Hope that helps - let me know - cheers

Comment: when I run `alien --scripts sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.norarch.rpm` I don't get a `.deb` file created. I get a folder called `sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84` which has a subfolder of `opt`. I have also verified that the JDK is installed and running properly.

Comment: @James, I can chat u through .